# Run website php script only if some time has passed

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo

I have a php function live on my webpage. It runs whenever someone reloads that page and probably when google etc. crawls it. I only want the major part of it to execute once every hour though.

I was thinking about storing a timestamp in a database and only execute it if 59 minutes has passed since it ran last. Is there a better/simpler way? Could it for instance be stored in some global lasting php variable or such?

It seems a bit overkill to create a table and only keep one timestamp in it. I don't have access to the local machine the code is stored on.

Thanks for any suggestion!

Comment: CRON seems like the way to go.

Comment: Maybe store the timestamp in a file?

Comment: No need for a DB for this. You could always create a file with PHP and store the dynamic value within.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As AmazingDreams said, using a [cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) job is probably the best approach for this, especially seeing as it looks as if you're wanting to run this script once every hour. If you're using Windows, you can use the [Windows Task Scheduler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Task_Scheduler) instead.

Comment: I dont think i can setup a cron-job on the machine. I'll look into it. Atm im using https://www.setcronjob.com/ to run it each hour. The major problem that i have is, i dont want it to run when it gets reloaded manually. I'll look into storing a timestamp in a file unless someone has a better idea :) thanks